# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fromObject' of undefined Fabric Custom Object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I created a subclass of `fabric.Polygon`. It is working well but I couldn't understand the concept of `fromObject()` method. I tried to create `fromObject` based on some answers on stackoverflow but so far I couldn't manage it to work. Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ohh0j02s/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed the `var Zone` to `fabric.Zone` and modified the `fabric.Zone.fromObject` function. See the updated fiddle for the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ohh0j02s/1/